# Why would my property be undefined on state in React?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

My property isLoading is a Boolean on state that I check to determine if the body of my render code is ready to be executed or should wait with a spinning loader.  When I examine state in the debugger isLoading is a boolean as it should be but when I further examine just isLoading it is undefined.  And this is within the same break point (I have done nothing else other than move my mouse to hover over a different property 1 second away).  This is really messing up my code as the isLoading property is then undefined for my if statement right below it, thus it's not waiting on my code to be ready.  Can anyone tell me why my isLoading property would be undefined even though when I look at state it's a Boolean??

```
    render() {
    const {isLoading} = this.state.isLoading;

    if (isLoading) {
        return (<Loader isVisible={true}/>);
    }
```

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: You probably meant `const { isLoading } = this.state`. Your current code is looking for `this.state.isLoading.isLoading` which does not exist.

Comment: const {isLoading} = this.state

Comment: either remove `{}` and use `const isLoading = this.state.isLoading` **or** use this: `const {isLoading} = this.state`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the issue is with your  `const {isLoading} = this.state.isLoading;`

it need to be `const {isLoading} = this.state;`

because according to your code `const {isLoading} = this.state.isLoading;` mean `this.state.isLoading.isLoading` wish return an undefined value

this should work fine

```
 render() {
    const {isLoading} = this.state;

    if (isLoading) {
        return (<Loader isVisible={true}/>);
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

isLoading does not actually exist, you probably ment something like this:

```
if (this.state.isLoading)
```

but you could also do object deconstructing by doing

```
const {isLoading} = this.state
```

then:

```
if(isLoading)
```

Answer (score 0):

use it this way `const {isLoading} = this.state`
that way your putting isLoading of isLoading in cont variable wich is undefined

Answer (score 0):

```
> const {isLoading} = this.state;
```

This should be the syntax. The above is known as destructuring and was introduced in ES6. In the above syntax, the variable is assigned the value of isLoading from component's state.

What you are trying to do will search for another isLoading within `this.state.isLoading`.